# Why Chomsky called postmodernist ideas "absurdities" when related to the "Third World"?

Tags: postmodernism, politics

What did Chomsky meant, when referring to the "Third World" in this passage ([video](https://youtu.be/OzrHwDOlTt8?t=1m16s), [transcription](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Noam_Chomsky#Anti-postmodernism)):

> It's all very inflated, you know a lot of prestige and so on – **it
>   has a terrible effect in the Third World**. In the First World, rich
>   countries, it doesn't really matter that much. So if a lot of nonsense
>   goes on in the Paris cafés or Yale comparative literature department –
>   well, okay. On the other hand **in the Third World, popular movements
>   really need serious intellectuals to participate. And if they're all
>   ranting postmodernist absurdities... well, they're gone**. I've seen
>   real examples – could give them to you.

And what was he talking about, when referring to "postmodernist absurdities"? Why does he consider postmodernists as being not "serious intellectuals"? Isn't Postmodernism a Left-wing movement?

Answer (score 2):

Some quick thoughts. It seems that Chomsky is worried about *losing the critical universality* that grounds political analysis; a condition, presumably, of any socialist revolution. But without examples it does seem to be somewhat bitter, decrying faddish-but-incoherent theorization as some kind of major "cause" of stalled third-world revolutions.

There were certainly leftist insurgencies over the last half-century powered by "postmodern" thinkers -- [the Italian movement *Autonomia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomism) seems like a quite plausible candidate here, associated with Antonio Negri's "workerism" and being strongly influenced by various strands of post-Marxism and situationism, etc.

There are certainly political dangers to "generalized relativism" and speculative detachment. But postmodernism is probably not best summed up this way; and may be better understood as a variegated family of experimental movements than as some holistic "unified field theory".

It may help to keep in mind that movements like situationism conditioned not only new aesthetic and logical relations "in theory" but also new forms of life, new capabilities and opportunities for social transformation; and have been instrumental in raising mass consciousness about the bad economic determination of existence under capitalism.

If you're worried about the decline of the left generally, or that postmodernism has left the universalism of "serious Marxism" in ruins: Lenin *still* walks around the world; and the strangest tongues still *do* understand him. (Consider maybe also here that postmodernism is also often a likely scapegoat for the right, existing today largely as an excuse to interrogate the "leftist" academy about its curriculum corrupting the youth...)

Comment: Italy is not "third world". Have you ever been to a country in the "third world", that wasn't in a vacation travel to take beautiful pictures on the beach?

Comment: seems a bit simplistic and fallacious, the enemy of my enemy etc.. and the situs would be misread as pomo, i think

Comment: Definitely agreed that Italy is well inside Europe :) I would love to see better examples -- if you've got a clearer one that maybe you think Chomsky is referring to, feel free to mention it

Comment: @user3293056 there are many readings, as usual. (Please do consider posting your own answer!)

Comment: @JosephWeissman sorry i have no idea what examples he has.

Comment: Yeah I really would like to know as well, it's difficult to respond much more specifically without that

Comment: i can imagine that the claim makes sense, that it's easier to get your education if you're post modern. but that's far too trivial to make an argument from, i don't even have anecdotes ha

Comment: Guattari went to Brazil for awhile, I believe there's even a book (something like *Molecular Revolution in Brazil*) -- this *may* be closer to the tenor of Chomsky's worry

Comment: that's interesting. my point was only that supposing pomo is hegemonic, it likely is for "third world" (not sure i should use that term) academics too. the SI did survive til '72, but 7 years before lyotard used the term and ofc they were a complex group. can't see pomo really existing before conceptual art (kosuth art after philosophy '69, 12 years after the SI). claiming the may riots were pomo just seems defeatist more than anything. no need to cite anyone

Comment: @JosephWeissman Of course I have. But I'm expecting to hear from the "philosophy experts" here first. ;)

Comment: @JosephWeissman Is your reference about Brazil "Guattari"? What about Celso Furtado?